# an unexpected HTTP status code was returned by the server

Tags: php, http, jasperserver

I have a problem with my jasper report who are on a jasper server
for integrate them in my php application with jaspersoft/rest-client.
(wamp: php:5.6.31,mySql 5.7.19)(Jasperserver 6.6)

```
require_once __DIR__ . "/vendor/autoload.php";

use Jaspersoft\Client\Client;
use Jaspersoft\Exception\RESTRequestException;

try{
$c = new Client(
                "http://localhost:8081/jasperserver-pro",
                "superuser",
                "superuser",
                "organization_1"
);
$report = $c->reportService()->runReport('/reports/Blank_A4_1', 'html');

echo $report;   

} catch (RESTRequestException $e) {
    echo 'RESTRequestException:';
    echo '</br>Exception message:   ',  $e->getMessage(), "\n";
    echo '</br>Set parameters:      ';
    var_dump($e->parameters);
    echo '</br>Expected status code:';
    var_dump($e->expectedStatusCodes);
    echo '</br>Error code:          ',  $e->errorCode, "\n";
}
```

I expected to see my report but actually I just have the exception "An unexpected HTTP status code was returned by the server "

The exact echo is :

```
RESTRequestException:
Exception message: An unexpected HTTP status code was returned by the server 
Set parameters:
C:\wamp64\www\TestBI\index.php:29:null

Expected status code:
C:\wamp64\www\TestBI\index.php:31:
array (size=1)
  0 => int 200

Error code:
```

Comment: It's fine, I find the answer and if someone want to know how, just leave a comment.

Comment: `</br>` — the start tag for the *br* element is mandatory, but the end tag is forbidden. This is nonsense.

Answer (score 0):

On some cases expectedStatusCodes is not retuned in response as an example of timeout or process termination.